# find greater than/equal value in a column excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm using the INDEX and MATCH function in Excel 2011 to find the exact date when a stock value (contained in the B2 cell) is matched.

This is my table: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s163/sh/1f56eee5-7323-49ff-ba11-9633560e5ad1/1ac623feb7609583f95fe5f219ba9d09

I've used the following formula:

=INDEX(A6:A24,MATCH(B2,D6:D24,0))

In the example below I got the following date: 9/5/14 12:45. And it's correct because it matches exactly that value.

But if I try the same formula matching the value 1.40964 I got a NA value.
And this is wrong because I should get the same date 9/5/14 12:45 as the 1.40964 is greater than 1.40963 and it means that the value has occurred.

How can I create a formula that matches for the greater than/exact value ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your table (or a sample) directly in your question.

Comment: this is my table https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3308227/test.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

In your test excel file, D10 value is 1.40963 so the N/A error occurs.

Try this -

=INDEX(A5:A29,MATCH(B1,D5:D29,1))

Comment: But using your formula if i try to search for the value 1.41060 I get the following date: 9/5/14 12:55.
While I should get the value: 9/5/14 13:00 as the corresponding 1.41075 value is greater than 1.41060.